# FTP : 421 Could not create socket

Tags: java, ftp-client

I am trying to develop FTP client in Java. I used Apache's org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient for client and used filezilla as the FTP server. But when I try to send multiple files, I get an error saying "421 Could not create socket" in the middle of the file upload. This error occurred randomly. I set up client as follows

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.connect(host, port);
ftp.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(100);
ftp.login(userName, password)
ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

And this is how I upload file

```
input = new FileInputStream(new File(localFilePath));
stream = this.ftp.storeFileStream( hostDirectory + fileName);
byte[] bytesIn = new byte[4096];
int read = 0;

while ((read = input.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
   stream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
}
```

Server log

```
(034082)2/27/2018 11:10:24 AM - user (127.0.0.1)> TYPE I
(034082)2/27/2018 11:10:24 AM - user (127.0.0.1)> 200 Type set to I
(034082)2/27/2018 11:10:24 AM - user (127.0.0.1)> PASV
(034082)2/27/2018 11:10:24 AM - user (127.0.0.1)> 421 Could not create socket.
(034082)2/27/2018 11:10:24 AM - user (127.0.0.1)> QUIT
(034082)2/27/2018 11:10:24 AM - user (127.0.0.1)> 221 Goodbye
(034082)2/27/2018 11:10:24 AM - user (127.0.0.1)> disconnected.
```

I tried FTP4j too but it also exhibit the same behavior. I tested filezilla client. It worked without any problem. I can't figure out what went wrong.
What might be the problem here?

Comment: _""421 Could not create socket" in the middle of the file upload"_ from the log it appears you get the error immediately on sending the PASV command, not in the middle of the transfer.

Comment: The server replies to PASV with a message telling the client what port to use for the DATA connection, which will be a random port > 1024.  If you have a very restrictive outgoing firewall (or are running behind a proxy) it could be preventing the DATA connection from going through.  You will have to watch the traffic using Wireshark to see what is happening at the protocol level.

Comment: That might be the problem. But server and client both run in the same host. So I am not sure how firewall affects. By the way I used the 0.9.42 version of FileZilla server and it work without a problem. To come up with this version I have tried several versions and all of them had different issues.